# VS2015 don't kill IIS process when debug is stopped

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis, process

After migration from VS2013(Ultimate) to VS2015(Enterprise) I have problem while debugging. Actually when I stop debug, change code and run again I get message " Unable to copy *.dll". This is becouse IIS Express process is still working, so I have to kill this process and then I can rerun my code. It is very annoying.

How can I force VS2015 to kill ISS process when I want to stop debugging?

Answer (score 1):

Try to uncheck option **Tools>Options>Debugging->Edit And Continue**,
check option **Tools>Options>IntelliTrace>General>Enable IntelliTrace** and select **IntelliTrace events only** option

Comment: Unfortunatly it doesn't work on my pc. Even after vs restart.

Comment: @Jacek Sorry, maybe I'm wrong with the first option. I had the same problem a few months ago and it was solved by enabling/disabling this option, but I can't check it right now. Try to enable **Edit And Continue** option instead of disabling.

Comment: @Jacek try also to enable **Enable Edit and Continue** option in Project options (**Web** tab, **Debuggers** section)